# Swift: Codable - extract a single coding key

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable, decodable

I have the following code to extract a JSON contained within a coding key:

```
let value = try! decoder.decode([String:Applmusic].self, from: $0["applmusic"])
```

This successfully handles the following JSONs:

```
{
  "applmusic":{
    "code":"AAPL",
    "quality":"good",
    "line":"She told me don't worry",
}
```

However, fails to extract a JSON with the coding key of `applmusic` from the following one:

```
{
  "applmusic":{
    "code":"AAPL",
    "quality":"good",
    "line":"She told me don't worry",
  },
  "spotify":{
    "differentcode":"SPOT",
    "music_quality":"good",
    "spotify_specific_code":"absent in apple"
  },
  "amazon":{
    "amzncode":"SPOT",
    "music_quality":"good",
    "stanley":"absent in apple"
  }
}
```

The data models for `applmusic`,`spotify` and `amazon` are different. However, I need only to extract `applmusic` and omit other coding keys.

My `Swift` data model is the following:

```
public struct Applmusic: Codable {
    public let code: String
    public let quality: String
    public let line: String
}
```

The API responds with the full JSON and I cannot ask it to give me only the needed fields.

How to decode only the specific part of the json? It seems, that `Decodable` requires me to deserialize the whole json first, so I have to know the full data model for it.

Obviously, one of the solutions would be to create a separate `Response` model just to contain the `applmusic`parameter, but it looks like a hack:

```
public struct Response: Codable {
    public struct Applmusic: Codable {
        public let code: String
        public let quality: String
        public let line: String
    }
    // The only parameter is `applmusic`, ignoring the other parts - works fine
    public let applmusic: Applmusic
}
```

Could you propose a better way to deal with such JSON structures?

**A little bit more insight**

I use it the following technique in the generic extension that automatically decodes the API responses for me. Therefore, I'd prefer to generalize a way for handling such cases, without the need to create a `Root` structure. What if the key I need is 3 layers deep in the JSON structure?

Here is the extension that does the decoding for me:

```
extension Endpoint where Response: Swift.Decodable {
  convenience init(method: Method = .get,
                   path: Path,
                   codingKey: String? = nil,
                   parameters: Parameters? = nil) {
    self.init(method: method, path: path, parameters: parameters, codingKey: codingKey) {
      if let key = codingKey {
        guard let value = try decoder.decode([String:Response].self, from: $0)[key] else {
          throw RestClientError.valueNotFound(codingKey: key)
        }
        return value
      }

      return try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: $0)
    }
  }
}
```

The API is defined like this:

```
extension API {
  static func getMusic() -> Endpoint<[Applmusic]> {
    return Endpoint(method: .get,
                    path: "/api/music",
                    codingKey: "applmusic")
  }
}
```

Comment: *one of the solutions* is the proper way to extract only one key.

Comment: Your `Response` is correct way to do this still   Try to get `applmusic` in separate object and try to decode it  may be it will work

Comment: You can do it via `nestedContainer` during `init(decoder)` without creating the `Response` wrapper

Comment: @vadian could you please elaborate on the "proper way to extract only one key"? Thank you.

Comment: @Tj3n could you please post a short example of your idea here?

Comment: Your *hack* example is perfectly fine. It's less effort than flatten the struct with `nestedContainer`.

Comment: @vadian Agree, it works, but I use the same JSON structure in mulitple places of the app. It would be great to generalize value retrieval. Please, take a look at "A little bit more insight" section, which I've added.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Updated: I made an extension of `JSONDecoder` out of this answer, you can check it here: https://github.com/aunnnn/NestedDecodable, it allows you to decode a nested model of any depth with a key path.*

You can use it like this:

```
let post = try decoder.decode(Post.self, from: data, keyPath: "nested.post")
```

---

You can make a `Decodable` wrapper (e.g., `ModelResponse` here), and put all the logic to extract nested model with a key inside that:

```
struct DecodingHelper {

    /// Dynamic key
    private struct Key: CodingKey {
        let stringValue: String
        init?(stringValue: String) {
            self.stringValue = stringValue
            self.intValue = nil
        }

        let intValue: Int?
        init?(intValue: Int) {
            return nil
        }
    }

    /// Dummy model that handles model extracting logic from a key
    private struct ModelResponse<NestedModel: Decodable>: Decodable {
        let nested: NestedModel

        public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let key = Key(stringValue: decoder.userInfo[CodingUserInfoKey(rawValue: "my_model_key")!]! as! String)!
            let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Key.self)
            nested = try values.decode(NestedModel.self, forKey: key)
        }
    }

    static func decode<T: Decodable>(modelType: T.Type, fromKey key: String) throws -> T {
        // mock data, replace with network response
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test", ofType: "json")!
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .mappedIfSafe)

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()

        // ***Pass in our key through `userInfo`
        decoder.userInfo[CodingUserInfoKey(rawValue: "my_model_key")!] = key
        let model = try decoder.decode(ModelResponse<T>.self, from: data).nested
        return model
    }
}
```

You can pass your desired key through `userInfo` of `JSONDecoder` (`"my_model_key"`). It is then converted to our dynamic `Key` inside `ModelResponse` to actually extract the model.

Then you can use it like this:

```
let appl = try DecodingHelper.decode(modelType: Applmusic.self, fromKey: "applmusic")
let amazon = try DecodingHelper.decode(modelType: Amazon.self, fromKey: "amazon")
let spotify = try DecodingHelper.decode(modelType: Spotify.self, fromKey: "spotify")
print(appl, amazon, spotify)
```

Full code:
https://gist.github.com/aunnnn/2d6bb20b9dfab41189a2411247d04904

---

### Bonus: Deeply nested key

After playing around more, I found you can easily decode a key of arbitrary depth with this modified `ModelResponse`:

```
private struct ModelResponse<NestedModel: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let nested: NestedModel

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        // Split nested paths with '.'
        var keyPaths = (decoder.userInfo[CodingUserInfoKey(rawValue: "my_model_key")!]! as! String).split(separator: ".")

        // Get last key to extract in the end
        let lastKey = String(keyPaths.popLast()!)

        // Loop getting container until reach final one
        var targetContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Key.self)
        for k in keyPaths {
            let key = Key(stringValue: String(k))!
            targetContainer = try targetContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: Key.self, forKey: key)
        }
        nested = try targetContainer.decode(NestedModel.self, forKey: Key(stringValue: lastKey)!)
    }
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
let deeplyNestedModel = try DecodingHelper.decode(modelType: Amazon.self, fromKey: "nest1.nest2.nest3")
```

From this json:

```
{
    "apple": { ... },
    "amazon": {
        "amzncode": "SPOT",
        "music_quality": "good",
        "stanley": "absent in apple"
    },
    "nest1": {
        "nest2": {
            "amzncode": "Nest works",
            "music_quality": "Great",
            "stanley": "Oh yes",

            "nest3": {
                "amzncode": "Nest works, again!!!",
                "music_quality": "Great",
                "stanley": "Oh yes"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Full code: https://gist.github.com/aunnnn/9a6b4608ae49fe1594dbcabd9e607834

Comment: amazing, just need a bit changes on the struct init to be able to pass in custom `decoder` and accept data like the original decoder then would be perfect

Comment: Thank you. Seems to be a bit more generalized approach, I definitely will play with it...

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need the nested struct `Applmusic` inside `Response`. This will do the job:

```
import Foundation

let json = """
{
    "applmusic":{
        "code":"AAPL",
        "quality":"good",
        "line":"She told me don't worry"
    },
    "I don't want this":"potatoe",
}
"""

public struct Applmusic: Codable {
    public let code: String
    public let quality: String
    public let line: String
}

public struct Response: Codable {
    public let applmusic: Applmusic
}

if let data = json.data(using: .utf8) {
    let value = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data).applmusic
    print(value) // Applmusic(code: "AAPL", quality: "good", line: "She told me don\'t worry")
}
```

**Edit: Addressing your latest comment**

If the JSON response would change in a way that the `applmusic` tag is nested, you would only need to properly change your `Response` type. Example:

New JSON (note that `applmusic` is now nested in a new `responseData` tag):

```
{
    "responseData":{
        "applmusic":{
            "code":"AAPL",
            "quality":"good",
            "line":"She told me don't worry"
        },
        "I don't want this":"potatoe",
    }   
}
```

The only change needed would be in `Response`:

```
public struct Response: Decodable {

    public let applmusic: Applmusic

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case responseData
    }

    enum ApplmusicKey: String, CodingKey {
        case applmusic
    }

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        let applmusicKey = try values.nestedContainer(keyedBy: ApplmusicKey.self, forKey: .responseData)
        applmusic = try applmusicKey.decode(Applmusic.self, forKey: .applmusic)
    }
}
```

The previous changes wouldn't break up any existing code, we are only fine-tuning the private implementation of how the `Response` parses the JSON data to correctly fetch an `Applmusic` object. All calls such as `JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data).applmusic` would remain the same.

## Tip

Finally, if you want to hide the `Response` wrapper logic altogether, you may have one public/exposed method which will do all the work; such as:

```
// (fine-tune this method to your needs)
func decodeAppleMusic(data: Data) throws -> Applmusic {
    return try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data).applmusic
}
```

Hiding the fact that `Response` even exists (make it private/inaccessible), will allow you to have all the code through your app **only** have to call `decodeAppleMusic(data:)`. For example:

```
if let data = json.data(using: .utf8) {
    let value = try! decodeAppleMusic(data: data)
    print(value) // Applmusic(code: "AAPL", quality: "good", line: "She told me don\'t worry")
}
```

Recommended read:

**Encoding and Decoding Custom Types**

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. I know that it was 2 weeks ago but I was wondering 
how it can be solved using library [KeyedCodable](https://github.com/dgrzeszczak/KeyedCodable/) I created. Here is my proposition with generic:

```
struct Response<Type>: Codable, Keyedable where Type: Codable {

    var responseObject: Type!

    mutating func map(map: KeyMap) throws {
        try responseObject <-> map[map.userInfo.keyPath]
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        try KeyedDecoder(with: decoder).decode(to: &self)
    }
}
```

helper extension:

```
private let infoKey = CodingUserInfoKey(rawValue: "keyPath")!
extension Dictionary where Key == CodingUserInfoKey, Value == Any {

   var keyPath: String {
        set { self[infoKey] = newValue }

        get {
            guard let key = self[infoKey] as? String else { return "" }
            return key
        }
    }
```

use:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.userInfo.keyPath = "applmusic"
let response = try? decoder.decode(Response<Applmusic>.self, from: jsonData)
```

Please notice that keyPath may be nested more deeply I mean it may be eg. "responseData.services.applemusic".

In addition Response is a Codable so you can encode it without any additional work.