# How to turn an alamofire response into an array of strings?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, alamofire, swift5

I am looking for extracting the code product of each "hit" of the request as an array of strings like : `self.rightcode = [code0,code1,code2,...]`

I have been trying for few days but I am struggling to insert something like `for i in 1...n` in my response string `String("\(response.value?.resultSet?.the0.result.the[i]?.code ?? "code not found")")`

Given the following Alamofire request :

```
var boncode1: String = ""    

func fetch(jan: String) {

    let itemSearch = "https://shopping.yahooapis.jp/ShoppingWebService/V1/json/itemSearch?appid=\(appId)&jan=\(jan)&hits=50"

        AF.request(itemSearch).responseDecodable(of: Welcome.self) { response in

        //load the code product

        self.rightcode = String("\(response.value?.resultSet?.the0.result.the0?.code ?? "code not found")")

        print(self.rightcode) }
```

Please find the json response belows if it can help :

(I have shortened the json to 3 cases : 0,1,2 to do not take space but in general, my requests hit between 20 and 50 cases)

```
    {
  "ResultSet": {
    "0": {
      "Result": {
        "0": {
          "Name": "東洋ナッツ食品　食塩無添加クラッシー　360g缶　1個",
          "Description": "現在ご注文混雑により、日時指定なしのご注文は最大2週間程度お待ちいただく状況です。 商品出荷時にご案内のメール（件名：商品発送のお知らせ）をお送りしておりますので、今しばらくお待ちくださいますようお願い申し上げます。  ※ご注文の確定タイミングにより、在庫が確保できない場合がございます。 「ご注文を確定」する際に再度ご確認ください。  こだわり派の食塩無添加ミックスナッツです 厳選したナッツを使用しています  スナック・お菓子 ＞ おつまみ・ドライフルーツ・ナッツ ＞ ドライフルーツ・ナッツ ＞ ドライナッツ",
          "Headline": "",
          "Url": "https://store.shopping.yahoo.co.jp/y-lohaco/1408892.html",
          "ReleaseDate": "",
          "Availability": "instock",
          "Code": "y-lohaco_1408892",
          "Condition": "new",
          "Image": {
            "Id": "y-lohaco_1408892",
            "Small": "https://item-shopping.c.yimg.jp/i/c/y-lohaco_1408892",
            "Medium": "https://item-shopping.c.yimg.jp/i/g/y-lohaco_1408892"
          },
          "Review": {
            "Rate": "0.00",
            "Count": "1",
            "Url": "https://shopping.yahoo.co.jp/review/item/list?store_id=y-lohaco&page_key=1408892"
          },
          "Affiliate": {
            "Rate": "1.0"
          },
          "Price": {
            "_attributes": {
              "currency": "JPY"
            },
            "_value": "1530"
          },
          "PremiumPrice": "",
          "PriceLabel": {
            "_attributes": {
              "taxIncluded": "true"
            },
            "FixedPrice": "",
            "DefaultPrice": "1530",
            "SalePrice": "",
            "PremiumPriceStatus": "0",
            "PremiumPrice": "1530",
            "PremiumDiscountType": "",
            "PremiumDiscountRate": "",
            "PeriodStart": "",
            "PeriodEnd": ""
          },
          "Point": {
            "Amount": "15",
            "Times": "1",
            "PremiumAmount": "15",
            "PremiumTimes": "1"
          },
          "Shipping": {
            "Code": "3",
            "Name": "条件付き送料無料"
          },
          "Category": {
            "Current": {
              "Id": "4963",
              "Name": "ミックスナッツ"
            }
          },
          "CategoryIdPath": {
            "0": {
              "Id": "1"
            },
            "1": {
              "Id": "2498"
            },
            "2": {
              "Id": "4745"
            },
            "3": {
              "Id": "1161"
            },
            "4": {
              "Id": "4963"
            },
            "5": {
              "Id": "1"
            },
            "6": {
              "Id": "2498"
            },
            "7": {
              "Id": "1313"
            },
            "8": {
              "Id": "14622"
            },
            "9": {
              "Id": "14673"
            },
            "_container": "Category"
          },
          "Brands": {
            "Name": "",
            "Path": {
              "0": {
                "Id": ""
              },
              "_container": "Brand"
            }
          },
          "JanCode": "4901998301727",
          "Model": "",
          "IsbnCode": "",
          "Store": {
            "Id": "y-lohaco",
            "Name": "LOHACO PayPayモール店",
            "Url": "https://paypaymall.yahoo.co.jp/store/y-lohaco/top/",
            "Payment": {
              "0": {
                "Code": "1",
                "Name": "クレジットカード"
              },
              "1": {
                "Code": "16",
                "Name": "Yahoo!ウォレットに登録しているクレジットカード"
              },
              "2": {
                "Code": "4096",
                "Name": "PayPay"
              },
              "_container": "Method"
            },
            "IsBestStore": "false",
            "Ratings": {
              "Rate": "4.5",
              "Count": "22835",
              "Total": "103475",
              "DetailRate": "4.5"
            },
            "Image": {
              "Id": "y-lohaco_1",
              "Medium": "https://item-shopping.c.yimg.jp/s/h/y-lohaco_1"
            },
            "IsPMallStore": "true"
          },
          "IsAdult": "0",
          "Deliveryinfo": {
            "Area": "",
            "Deadline": "",
            "Day": ""
          },
          "_attributes": {
            "index": "1"
          }
        },
        "1": {
          "Name": "東洋ナッツ食品 食塩無添加 クラッシー ミックスナッツ缶 ( 360g )/ TON'S",
          "Description": "東洋ナッツ食品 食塩無添加 クラッシー ミックスナッツ缶(TON Classy)/ドライフルーツ・ナッツ/ブランド：TON'S/【発売元、製造元、輸入元又は販売元】東洋ナッツ食品/(/F214902/F214902/)/【東洋ナッツ食品 食塩無添加 クラッシー ミックスナッツ缶の商品詳細】●無添加タイプのミックスナッツ缶です。●味付けせずに素材を生かすローストで仕上げました。●落花生を配合していません。",
          "Headline": "TON'S",
          "Url": "https://store.shopping.yahoo.co.jp/kenkocom/e243253h.html",
          "ReleaseDate": "",
          "Availability": "instock",
          "Code": "kenkocom_e243253h",
          "Condition": "new",
          "Image": {
            "Id": "kenkocom_e243253h",
            "Small": "https://item-shopping.c.yimg.jp/i/c/kenkocom_e243253h",
            "Medium": "https://item-shopping.c.yimg.jp/i/g/kenkocom_e243253h"
          },
          "Review": {
            "Rate": "4.65",
            "Count": "65",
            "Url": "https://shopping.yahoo.co.jp/review/item/list?store_id=kenkocom&page_key=e243253h"
          },
          "Affiliate": {
            "Rate": "1.0"
          },
          "Price": {
            "_attributes": {
              "currency": "JPY"
            },
            "_value": "1458"
          },
          "PremiumPrice": "",
          "PriceLabel": {
            "_attributes": {
              "taxIncluded": "true"
            },
            "FixedPrice": "",
            "DefaultPrice": "1458",
            "SalePrice": "",
            "PremiumPriceStatus": "0",
            "PremiumPrice": "1458",
            "PremiumDiscountType": "",
            "PremiumDiscountRate": "",
            "PeriodStart": "",
            "PeriodEnd": ""
          },
          "Point": {
            "Amount": "14",
            "Times": "1",
            "PremiumAmount": "14",
            "PremiumTimes": "1"
          },
          "Shipping": {
            "Code": "3",
            "Name": "条件付き送料無料"
          },
          "Category": {
            "Current": {
              "Id": "4963",
              "Name": "ミックスナッツ"
            }
          },
          "CategoryIdPath": {
            "0": {
              "Id": "1"
            },
            "1": {
              "Id": "2498"
            },
            "2": {
              "Id": "4745"
            },
            "3": {
              "Id": "1161"
            },
            "4": {
              "Id": "4963"
            },
            "5": {
              "Id": "1"
            },
            "6": {
              "Id": "2498"
            },
            "7": {
              "Id": "1313"
            },
            "8": {
              "Id": "14622"
            },
            "9": {
              "Id": "14673"
            },
            "_container": "Category"
          },
          "Brands": {
            "Name": "",
            "Path": {
              "0": {
                "Id": ""
              },
              "_container": "Brand"
            }
          },
          "JanCode": "4901998301727",
          "Model": "",
          "IsbnCode": "",
          "Store": {
            "Id": "kenkocom",
            "Name": "ケンコーコム",
            "Url": "https://store.shopping.yahoo.co.jp/kenkocom/",
            "Payment": {
              "0": {
                "Code": "1",
                "Name": "クレジットカード"
              },
              "1": {
                "Code": "16",
                "Name": "Yahoo!ウォレットに登録しているクレジットカード"
              },
              "2": {
                "Code": "4",
                "Name": "商品代引"
              },
              "3": {
                "Code": "4096",
                "Name": "PayPay"
              },
              "_container": "Method"
            },
            "IsBestStore": "false",
            "Ratings": {
              "Rate": "4.5",
              "Count": "240786",
              "Total": "1068536",
              "DetailRate": "4.4"
            },
            "Image": {
              "Id": "kenkocom_1",
              "Medium": "https://item-shopping.c.yimg.jp/s/h/kenkocom_1"
            },
            "IsPMallStore": "false"
          },
          "IsAdult": "0",
          "Deliveryinfo": {
            "Area": "",
            "Deadline": "",
            "Day": ""
          },
          "_attributes": {
            "index": "2"
          }
        },
        "2": {
          "Name": "東洋ナッツ食品　食塩無添加　クラッシーミックスナッツ缶　３６０ｇ　１缶",
          "Description": "メーカー：東洋ナッツ食品  品番：740819  持ち味の違う6つのナッツをミックスしました。人気の食塩無添加タイプ。",
          "Headline": "【1回のご注文が税込3,000円以上で送料無料！（沖縄を除く）】",
          "Url": "https://store.shopping.yahoo.co.jp/tanomail/0678982.html",
          "ReleaseDate": "",
          "Availability": "instock",
          "Code": "tanomail_0678982",
          "Condition": "new",
          "Image": {
            "Id": "tanomail_0678982",
            "Small": "https://item-shopping.c.yimg.jp/i/c/tanomail_0678982",
            "Medium": "https://item-shopping.c.yimg.jp/i/g/tanomail_0678982"
          },
          "Review": {
            "Rate": "4.57",
            "Count": "7",
            "Url": "https://shopping.yahoo.co.jp/review/item/list?store_id=tanomail&page_key=0678982"
          },
          "Affiliate": {
            "Rate": "1.0"
          },
          "Price": {
            "_attributes": {
              "currency": "JPY"
            },
            "_value": "1497"
          },
          "PremiumPrice": "",
          "PriceLabel": {
            "_attributes": {
              "taxIncluded": "true"
            },
            "FixedPrice": "",
            "DefaultPrice": "1497",
            "SalePrice": "",
            "PremiumPriceStatus": "0",
            "PremiumPrice": "1497",
            "PremiumDiscountType": "",
            "PremiumDiscountRate": "",
            "PeriodStart": "",
            "PeriodEnd": ""
          },
          "Point": {
            "Amount": "14",
            "Times": "1",
            "PremiumAmount": "14",
            "PremiumTimes": "1"
          },
          "Shipping": {
            "Code": "3",
            "Name": "条件付き送料無料"
          },
          "Category": {
            "Current": {
              "Id": "13451",
              "Name": "その他スナック、お菓子、おつまみ"
            }
          },
          "CategoryIdPath": {
            "0": {
              "Id": "1"
            },
            "1": {
              "Id": "2498"
            },
            "2": {
              "Id": "4745"
            },
            "3": {
              "Id": "13451"
            },
            "_container": "Category"
          },
          "Brands": {
            "Name": "",
            "Path": {
              "0": {
                "Id": ""
              },
              "_container": "Brand"
            }
          },
          "JanCode": "4901998301727",
          "Model": "740819",
          "IsbnCode": "",
          "Store": {
            "Id": "tanomail",
            "Name": "ぱーそなるたのめーる",
            "Url": "https://paypaymall.yahoo.co.jp/store/tanomail/top/",
            "Payment": {
              "0": {
                "Code": "1",
                "Name": "クレジットカード"
              },
              "1": {
                "Code": "16",
                "Name": "Yahoo!ウォレットに登録しているクレジットカード"
              },
              "2": {
                "Code": "4",
                "Name": "商品代引"
              },
              "3": {
                "Code": "4096",
                "Name": "PayPay"
              },
              "_container": "Method"
            },
            "IsBestStore": "true",
            "Ratings": {
              "Rate": "4.5",
              "Count": "37923",
              "Total": "172500",
              "DetailRate": "4.5"
            },
            "Image": {
              "Id": "tanomail_1",
              "Medium": "https://item-shopping.c.yimg.jp/s/h/tanomail_1"
            },
            "IsPMallStore": "true"
          },
          "IsAdult": "0",
          "Deliveryinfo": {
            "Area": "",
            "Deadline": "",
            "Day": ""
          },
          "_attributes": {
            "index": "3"
          }
        },
        "Request": {
          "Query": ""
        },
        "Modules": "",
        "_container": "Hit"
      }
    },
    "totalResultsAvailable": "30",
    "totalResultsReturned": 30,
    "firstResultPosition": "1"
  }
}
```

Comment: have a look at SwiftyJSON it can help you,  https://cocoapods.org/pods/SwiftyJSON

Comment: Maybe you can try the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50395314/3224710

Comment: Glad to know that :)